# Joomla nested menu item route alias

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to set up a menu with a top level item as `/bikes` which is a page builder page, and the native joomla category blog page as `/news/bikes`. I have a top level item `news` and a top level item `bikes` but when I try to add a sub menu item with `news` as the parent and `bikes` as the alias, it doesn't work because menu item aliases can't be the same as any other item, so it just throws an error and I've had to use `bikes-news` as the sub item alias.

Does any body know of a way to have a nested route/sub menu item with the same alias as a top level menu item/route?

My current menu structure is

```
news (/news)
- bikes-news (/news/bikes-news)
bikes (/bikes)
```

but what I want is

```
news (/news)
- bikes (/news/bikes)
bikes (/bikes)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use a hidden menu for your alias menu items?

Comment: @jonboy People seem to keep getting confused between a menu item type alias and a menu item route alias. I'm talking about routes not types. Thanks

Comment: Joomla-specific questions are always welcome at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Come join us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue on github helped a lot https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/14034

It turns out you can't have any route alias the same as any top level menu item route alias

I worked around this by having `/bikes` for the main page and for the native joomla blog `/bikes/latest`